# cannot find name __values

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am trying to run an example built in using typescript(using version 2.6) of async iterator through browser.

`

```
function* countAppleSales () {
  var saleList = [3, 7, 5];
  for (var i = 0; i < saleList.length; i++) {
    yield saleList[i];
  }
}
for(let val of countAppleSales())
    console.log(val);

async function* asyncRandomNumbers() {
    // This is a web service that returns a random number
    const url = 'https://www.random.org/decimal-fractions/?num=1&dec=10&col=1&format=plain&rnd=new';

    while (true) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const text = await response.text();
      yield Number(text);
    }
  }

  async function example() {
    for await (const number of asyncRandomNumbers()) {
      console.log(number);
      if (number > 0.95) break;
    }
  }

  example();

  console.log('we are after await')
```

;`

above code is running fine in browser but am getting error cannot find name __values logged in console.log.

below is the type script configuration file am using:

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "es2015",
      "types": [
        "node"
       ],
     // typeRoots option has been previously configured
     "typeRoots": [
        // add path to @types
        "node_modules/@types"
     ],
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "downlevelIteration": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "watch": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      //"noEmitHelpers": true,
      "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
      "strictNullChecks": false,
      "outDir": "tmp",
      //"lib":["es2017","es2015","es2016","es2015.generator","esnext","dom","esnext.asynciterable"]
      "lib": [ "es2017","dom","es2015.generator","es2015","es2015.iterable","esnext.asynciterable","esnext"]
  },
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
  "baseUrl": ".",

  "paths": {
    "lodash/*": [
      "node_modules/@types/lodash-es/*"
    ]},

    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
      "useBabel": true,
      "useCache": true
    },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "test"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
]
}
```

please can anybody help with this issue

Comment: And where is `__values` coming from? I don't see it in your code. Further, I suspect that you can't do things like: `async function* asyncRandomNumbers` (async generator)

Comment: this issue is resolved now, Issue is due to copy pasting typescript loader rules configuration twice in webpack configuration file. webpack error needs to be more specific though.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is resolved now, Issue is due to copy pasting  typescript loader rules configuration twice in webpack configuration file. webpack error needs to be more specific though.